Is "Gewißheit" (certainty or so) accessible to everyone according to Kant?
So during an argument about the spirit of the enlightenment era, which massively influenced modern science, if I'm not mistaken, I was arguing with someone else about the following key question:
Is it so that, according to Kant, that (possibly with the exception of the mentally ill etc., Kant sometimes makes such exceptions if I'm not mistaken) everyone is able to (at least if given the resources needed, that is, for example, enough time, and raw experimental results if necessary) recognize a correct derivation of a "certainty" ("Gewißheit") as such?
The guy pulled up a text snippet, which he identified as from the "KrV", "erster Absatz von B850" (first Paragraph of B850), which contains (on line 33 to 35) the sentence:
"Die subjektive Zugänglichkeit heißt Überzeugung (für mich selbst), die objektive, Gewißheit (für jedermann)."
I understood this sentence as stating that objective certainty is accessible (in the sense that it can be recognized as such, at least under reasonable conditions) to (without maybe the exception of the mentally ill etc., Kant sometimes makes such exceptions if I'm not mistaken) everyone, answering the key question affirmatively.
He doesn't think so, if I'm not mistaken.
Now that sentence sounds pretty clear to me, but as I am not really familiar with Kant's philosophy regarding epistemic questions, it is of course possible that I am mistaken somehow.
So I would like to ask you here: How would the key question be answered from the "Kantian perspective"? I am not searching for simple "yes/no" answers, I would love to get detailed answers, so I can understand the "Kantian perspective" a bit better : )

Good question! Hope I'll find time to answer. Until then, for context, I'll refer to this answer of mine since it makes more clear where the snippet you quote is used.

Thanks, I'll have a look...
